# Apply CSS transition to styled-component when React state changes

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions, styled-components

I have some state that changes after button click. The state changes the size of a sidebar.

Here is my CSS made with [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) and conditional rendering:

```js
const SidebarStyled = styled.div`
    width: ${this.state.sidebarOpen ? '200px' : '70px'};
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #0c1635;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
`;
```

Any idea how I can apply a `transition 0.2s` on the conditional rendering?

I have tried to add `transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;` and it didn't work.

Comment: You don't want to access `this.state` within a styled component declaration, you want to pass in a prop. I'd suggest reading the documentation, starting here - [Styled Components Basic: Adapting based on props](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props).

Comment: This project is from a client, and he does not want to change his component....

Comment: Then they are using styled-components incorrectly, and you won't be able to animate this. By defining the component within a component method (I'm guessing its `render()`), you are recreating that DOM element every time, so there is no way to have CSS transitions apply because the element is constantly getting recreated.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment, you need to [pass in a prop and interpolate](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props) it out to change your CSS. Otherwise your component will re-render, and the CSS transition won't be applied.

```js
const { React, ReactDOM, styled } = window;

class WontWork extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { sidebarOpen: false };
    }

    render() {
        const Sidebar = styled.div`
            width: ${this.state.sidebarOpen ? "200px" : "70px"};
            height: 20px;
            background: red;
            transition: width 1s;
        `;

        return (
            <main>
                <p>This won't work:</p>
                <Sidebar />
                <button
                    onClick={() => this.setState({ sidebarOpen: !this.state.sidebarOpen })}
                >
                    Expand
                </button>
            </main>
        );
    }
}

const WorkingSidebar = styled.div`
    width: ${(props) => (props.open ? "200px" : "70px")};
    height: 20px;
    background: green;
    transition: width 1s;
`;

class WillWork extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { sidebarOpen: false };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <main>
                <p>You need to pass in a <b>prop</b> to a predefined styled-component:</p>
                <WorkingSidebar open={this.state.sidebarOpen} />
                <button
                    onClick={() => this.setState({ sidebarOpen: !this.state.sidebarOpen })}
                >
                    Expand
                </button>
            </main>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <WontWork />
        <hr />
        <WillWork />
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.14.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.14.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-is@16.13.1/umd/react-is.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/styled-components@5.3.3/dist/styled-components.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can passe `sidebarOpen` as props:

```
<SidebarStyle sidebarOpen = {this.state.sidebarOpen}>
```

Then:

```
const sidebarStyle = styled.div`
     width: 70px;
     transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
     transform: ${props.sidebarOpen ? "scaleX(3)" : "scaleX(1)"};
     .
     .
     .
`
```

I helped from here:

See here: [Adding transitions to styled components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44459813/adding-transitions-to-styled-components)

Does it work In this case?

Comment: No it does not work :/. Thank you for trying !

Answer (score -1):

Add a transition property like: `transition:all 200ms ease-in;`

Comment: i tried it, it does not work. Still no transition

Comment: did the size of sidebar increasing?

Comment: The size of the sidebar change yes. But with no transition